# How to remove space between bars in achart engine Android

Tags: android

> Hi, please help me to remove space between bars in chart    and set
>   bars very close. have tried many ways.     Anyone have solution,
>   please suggest me.Thanks in advance.The following is my code.

```
     void drawChart(String[] items, float[] amount){
             XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
                XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                XYSeries[] qtySeries =  new XYSeries[amount.length];
                XYSeriesRenderer[] qtyRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer[amount.length];
                for(int i=0;i<amount.length ;i++){
                    qtySeries[i] = new XYSeries("");
                    qtySeries[i].add(i,amount[i]);
                    dataset.addSeries(qtySeries[i]);
                    qtyRenderer[i] = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                    qtyRenderer[i].setColor(color[i]);
                    qtyRenderer[i].setDisplayChartValues(true);
                    qtyRenderer[i].setChartValuesTextSize(15);
                    qtyRenderer[i].setChartValuesSpacing(22);
                    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(qtyRenderer[i]);
                    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, items[i]);
                }
                float max=amount[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
                    if (amount[i] > max) {
                        max = amount[i];
                    }
                }
                mRenderer.setYAxisMax(max + 20);
                mRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.VERTICAL);
                mRenderer.setBarWidth(40f);
                mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
                mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
                mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
                mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
                mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
                mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false,false);
                mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
                mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.WHITE);
                mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(0.0f);
                mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
                mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.0f);

                lLytHourlyChart.removeAllViews();
                lLytHourlyChart.addView(ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getActivity(), dataset, mRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT));
            }
```

Comment: mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5); remove this

Comment: thanks, but it is not working here.

Comment: u added setBarSpacing twice

Comment: have removed. but no change

Comment: for checking only, can u add a -ve value to that. is there is any change while u very the bar spacing

Comment: thanks.. it is working

Comment: if it is working plz accept the answer. it will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

add bar spacing

```
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-1);
```